# How to save the state of the check position items in a multiple choice list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-checkbox, multipleselection

Here I am using adapter to show multiple selection list view with search functionality but when i select the item without filtering list view getting me correct checked list items but when i filtered list view getting wrong checked item, then how to save state of checked item when filtered list.Following is my adapter class code.

```
public class List_Filter_Multi_SelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List_Filter> {
    private Context context;
    private List<List_Filter> user_list;
    private List<List_Filter>original_userList;
    private Filter userFilter;
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

/*  public List_Filter_Multi_SelectAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List_Filter[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            myChecked.put(i, false);
        }
    }*/
    public List_Filter_Multi_SelectAdapter(List<List_Filter> user_list, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_for_multiple_selection, user_list);
        this.user_list = user_list;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.original_userList = user_list;
        for(int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++){
            myChecked.put(i, false);
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return user_list.size();
    }

    public List_Filter getItem(int position) {
        return user_list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return user_list.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    private static class memberHolder {
        public TextView memberNameView;

    }

    /*public void filter(String charText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

          filterOfMember.clear();
        for (String element :listOfuserName) {
             if (element.toLowerCase().contains(charText.toString().toLowerCase())) {
             filterOfMember.add(element);
                }
             }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }*/

    public void toggleChecked(int position){
        if(myChecked.get(position)){
            myChecked.put(position, false);
        }else{
            myChecked.put(position, true);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPositions(){
        List<Integer> checkedItemPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++){
            if (myChecked.get(i)){
                (checkedItemPositions).add(i);
            }
        }

        return checkedItemPositions;
    }

    public List<String> getCheckedItems(){
        List<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++){
            if (myChecked.get(i)){
                List_Filter p = user_list.get(i);
                (checkedItems).add(p.getName());

            }
         }

        return checkedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        memberHolder holder=new memberHolder();

        CheckedTextView checkedTextView;
        if(row==null){
            List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row=li.inflate(R.layout.row_for_multiple_selection, parent, false);     
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);
            holder.memberNameView = tv;
            row.setTag(holder);
           checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);

            checkedTextView.setText((CharSequence) p.getName());
        }else{

            List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);

            holder = (memberHolder) row.getTag();

            //List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);
            holder.memberNameView.setText(p.getName());
             checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);

                checkedTextView.setText(holder.memberNameView.getText());

        }



        Boolean checked = myChecked.get(position);
        if (checked != null) {
            checkedTextView.setChecked(checked);
       }
        return row;
    }
    public void resetData() {
        user_list = original_userList;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (userFilter == null)
            userFilter = new userNameFilter();

        return userFilter;
    }

    private class userNameFilter extends Filter {



        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = original_userList;
                results.count = original_userList.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<List_Filter> nUserList = new ArrayList<List_Filter>();

                for (List_Filter p : user_list) {
                    if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nUserList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nUserList;
                results.count = nUserList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                user_list = (List<List_Filter>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in your ***myChecked*** list you save the real position of item (their position in *original_userList* not their position in the list after filter).
you can add a boolean parameter to your List_Filter.class to save check state or you create another class that extands from List_Filter and add this parameter

```
    public class Checked_List_Filter extends List_Filter{
        boolean isChecked;
}
```

and your code become:

```
   public class List_Filter_Multi_SelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List_Filter> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Checked_List_Filter> user_list;
    private List<List_Filter>original_userList;
    private Filter userFilter;


    public List_Filter_Multi_SelectAdapter(List<List_Filter> user_list, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_for_multiple_selection, user_list);
        this.user_list = user_list;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.original_userList = user_list;
        for(int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++){
            user_list.get(i).isChecked = false;
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return user_list.size();
    }

    public Ckecked_List_Filter getItem(int position) {
        return user_list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return user_list.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    private static class memberHolder {
        public TextView memberNameView;

    }

    /*public void filter(String charText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

          filterOfMember.clear();
        for (String element :listOfuserName) {
             if (element.toLowerCase().contains(charText.toString().toLowerCase())) {
             filterOfMember.add(element);
                }
             }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }*/

    public void toggleChecked(int position){
        if(user_list.get(position).isChecked){
            user_list.get(position).isChecked = false;
        }else{
            user_list.get(position).isChecked = true;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPositions(){
        List<Integer> checkedItemPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++){
            if user_list.get(position).isChecked){
                (checkedItemPositions).add(i);
            }
        }

        return checkedItemPositions;
    }

    public List<String> getCheckedItems(){
        List<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++){
            if (user_list.get(position).isChecked){
                Checked_List_Filter p = user_list.get(i);
                (checkedItems).add(p.getName());

            }
         }

        return checkedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        memberHolder holder=new memberHolder();

        CheckedTextView checkedTextView;
        if(row==null){
            Checked_List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row=li.inflate(R.layout.row_for_multiple_selection, parent, false);     
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);
            holder.memberNameView = tv;
            row.setTag(holder);
           checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);

            checkedTextView.setText((CharSequence) p.getName());
        }else{

            Checked_List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);

            holder = (memberHolder) row.getTag();

            //List_Filter p = user_list.get(position);
            holder.memberNameView.setText(p.getName());
             checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textForMultiselection);

                checkedTextView.setText(holder.memberNameView.getText());

        }



        Boolean checked = user_list.get(position).isChecked;
        if (checked != null) {
            checkedTextView.setChecked(checked);
       }
        return row;
    }
    public void resetData() {
        user_list = original_userList;//TODO try to cast objects and set isChecked  to false 
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (userFilter == null)
            userFilter = new userNameFilter();

        return userFilter;
    }

  //.........
}
```

Comment: Hi Rami Thanks It working perfect........You really save my time and increase my knowledge as well thanks a lot...